# Vertical lines in a table

Tags: tables

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'paper2'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Comparison of the CCSHR estimators based on beta and logit-normal distributions}
    \begin{tabular}{cc|ccc|ccc}
\toprule
      &       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCSHR\_11} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCSHR\_12} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{mu} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{sigma} & Beta  & Logit-normal & TRUE  & Beta  & Logit-normal & TRUE \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.33} & 2.099 (0.134) & 2.106 (0.170) & 2.053 & 1.918 (0.129) & 1.915 (0.132) & 1.947 \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1.00} & 2.359 (0.170) & 2.348 (0.187) & 2.347 & 1.665 (0.134) & 1.677 (0.143) & 1.653 \\
(many lines omitted)
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

[image]

Here are my LaTeX code for a table and the result.
I intended to add vertical lines between the 2nd and 3rd columns and between 5th and 6th columns.
But the 1st vertical line appears only in the 1st row and the 2nd vertical line is shown in the 2nd row and beyond.
How can I modify these TeX code so that I can see both vertical lines at all rows?

This code is generated from Excel2LaTeX add-in.

Comment: The output uses the [`booktabs` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). And if you read the [`booktabs` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) you will see it mentions to "Never, ever use vertical rules." Through spacing one can provide sufficient dividers and groups within the table.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your table is wider than the text width. Those `\multicolumn{1}{c}{..} are all redundant, hence you can remove them. With these, your table becomes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'paper2'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{Comparison of the CCSHR estimators based on beta and logit-normal distributions}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
    \begin{tabular}{cc|ccc|ccc}
\toprule
      &       & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{CCSHR\_11} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCSHR\_12} \\
\midrule
mu & sigma & Beta  & Logit-normal & TRUE  & Beta  & Logit-normal & TRUE \\ \hline
0 & 0.33 & 2.099 (0.134) & 2.106 (0.170) & 2.053 & 1.918 (0.129) & 1.915 (0.132) & 1.947 \\
0 & 1.00 & 2.359 (0.170) & 2.348 (0.187) & 2.347 & 1.665 (0.134) & 1.677 (0.143) & 1.653 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have centered the table using `\makebox`.

As the saying goes, why to use vertical lines at all? Here is an improved version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'paper2'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{Comparison of the CCSHR estimators based on beta and logit-normal distributions}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
    \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\toprule
      &       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCSHR\_11} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCSHR\_12} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
mu & sigma & Beta  & Logit-normal & TRUE  & Beta  & Logit-normal & TRUE \\ \midrule
0 & 0.33 & 2.099 (0.134) & 2.106 (0.170) & 2.053 & 1.918 (0.129) & 1.915 (0.132) & 1.947 \\
0 & 1.00 & 2.359 (0.170) & 2.348 (0.187) & 2.347 & 1.665 (0.134) & 1.677 (0.143) & 1.653 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As has been mentioned in the comments, the first rule of the `booktabs` documentation is to *never* use vertical rules.

Here's an improvement that features:

- use of the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package for formatting numbers and uncertainties in tabular material,
- no vertical rules, instead using white space and `\cmidrule`s with trimmed sides to show the grouping, and
- slight adjustments to `\tabcolsep` and `\cmidrulekern` to fit the table in the text width.

**Commented Code:**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{0.5em} % provide space between caption and top rule

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbp] % don't use ! as it *ignores* LaTeX's best choice!
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.7pt}     % slight adjustment to fit text width
\setlength{\cmidrulekern}{0.25em} % adjust for decreased col sep
\caption{Comparison of the CCSHR estimators based on beta and logit-normal distributions}
\begin{tabular}{%
  S[table-format=1.0]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  *{2}{ % we need 2 copies of the below sequence
    *{2}{S[table-format=1.3(3)]} % number of digits in the column; form: numbers.decimals(uncertainty)
    S[table-format=1.3]
  }
}
  \toprule
  & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCSHR\_11}     
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCSHR\_12}    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-5}                  
    \cmidrule(lr){6-8}
  {$\mu$} & {$\sigma$} & {Beta} & {Logit-normal} & {TRUE}  % protect text headers with braces
                       & {Beta} & {Logit-normal} & {TRUE} \\
  \midrule
  0 & 0.33 & 2.099 \pm 0.134 & 2.106 \pm 0.170 & 2.053 & 1.918 \pm 0.129 & 1.915 \pm 0.132 & 1.947 \\
  0 & 1.00 & 2.359 \pm 0.170 & 2.348 \pm 0.187 & 2.347 & 1.665 \pm 0.134 & 1.677 \pm 0.143 & 1.653 \\
  %(many lines omitted)
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Other Notes:**
I'm not sure about the lines you omitted, but if μ is 0 for every row in a particular table, you could remove that column and write `$\mu=0$` somewhere in the headers or caption instead. This would save some space, reducing or eliminating the required adjustments to `\tabcolsep` (default `6pt`) and `\cmidrulekern` (default `0.5em`).

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?  Forgot to put a vertical line in, for example, `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{sigma}` where you need the lines to appear.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{hhline,booktabs,amsmath}
    \usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
\caption{Comparison of the CCSHR estimators based on beta and logit-normal distributions}
\begin{tabular}{cc|ccc|ccc}
\toprule
      &       & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{CCSHR\_11} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCSHR\_12} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{mu} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{sigma} & Beta  & Logit-normal & TRUE  & Beta  & Logit-normal & TRUE \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.33} & 2.099 (0.134) & 2.106 (0.170) & 2.053 & 1.918 (0.129) & 1.915 (0.132) & 1.947 \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.00} & 2.359 (0.170) & 2.348 (0.187) & 2.347 & 1.665 (0.134) & 1.677 (0.143) & 1.653 \\
%(many lines omitted)
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```