# How to draw a vertical line table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I search here, [Vertical lines in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198440/vertical-lines-in-a-table), it suggests something like:

```
 \begin{tabular}{cc|ccc|ccc}
```

[image]

I am using:

```
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}}{\textbf{Bootstrap}} \\
\cmidrule{4-8}
```

But does not fit in.

I wish to get the following:
[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
% \begin{center}
    %\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}M*{6}{N}@{}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}cXcccccc}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}}{\textbf{Bootstrap}} \\
\cmidrule{4-8}
    & 
    &  \multirow{4.5}{*}{\textbf{Mean}} 
    &  \multirow{4.5}{*}{\textbf{Bias}} 
    & \multirow{4.5}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Std.}\\ \textbf{Error}}}  
    & \multirow{4.5}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Sig.}\\ \textbf{(2-tailed)}}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}}{\textbf{95\% Confidence Interval of the Difference}}  
    \\
\cmidrule{7-8}  %\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
     & & & & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Lower}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Upper}} \\
\midrule
    Pair 1 
    & \textit{Testing example dataset} (AA) - \textit{Testing puree Example Dataset} (BB) 
    & 44.76\% 
    &  0.19\%  
    & 4.35 
    & 0.001 
    & 36.67\% 
    & 53.33\%\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your objective isn't clear. Judging by the screenshot you posted, you want to draw a vertical line *through* the word "bootstrap". Is this impression correct? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico, yes. Correct. Add a verticle line using my current MWE.

Answer (score 6):

I would no add vertical line(s), rather use appropriate `\cmidrule`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
 \usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row

    \begin{document}
        \begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{round-mode = places,
         round-precision=2,
         detect-weight
         }
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Bootstrap for paired Samples Test}
\label{tab:blabla}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
                {@{} l L *{3}{S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post={\,\%}]}
                              S[table-format=1.3]
                         *{2}{S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post={\,\%}]}
                 @{}}
        \toprule
        &   &               & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Bootstrap}                                 \\
        \cmidrule{4-8}
        &   &               &               &               &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\SI{95}{\%} Confidence\\ Interval}}                       \\
        \cmidrule{7-8}
        &   & {Mean}        & {Bias}        & {\thead{SE\tnote{a}}} & {\thead{STT\tnote{b}}}
                                                                    & {\thead{Lower}}
                                                                        & {\thead{Upper}}   \\
        \midrule
Pair 1  & Testing example dataset (BB) - Testing Example Dataset (AA)
            & 12.34567\%    & 12.34567\%    & 12.34567\%    & 1.234 & 12.34567\%    & 12.34567\%    \cr
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]
\item[a]    SE: Standard Error
\item[b]    STT: Signal (Two Tailed)
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

(MWE is based on [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514751/how-to-split-the-word-into-2-row-in-table/514777#514777))

However, if you persist to have it:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
 \usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row

    \begin{document}
        \begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{round-mode = places,
         round-precision=2,
         detect-weight
         }
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Bootstrap for paired Samples Test}
\label{tab:blabla}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
                {@{} l L *{3}{S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post={\,\%}]|}
                              S[table-format=1.3]|
                              S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post={\,\%}]|
                              S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post={\,\%}] 
                 @{}}
        \hline
        &   &               & \multicolumn{5}{|c}{Bootstrap}                                 \\
        \cline{4-8}
        &   &               &               &               &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\SI{95}{\%} Confidence\\ Interval}}                       \\
        \cline{7-8}
        &   & {Mean}        & {Bias}        & {\thead{SE\tnote{a}}} & {\thead{STT\tnote{b}}}
                                                                    & {\thead{Lower}}
                                                                        & {\thead{Upper}}   \\
        \hline
Pair 1  & Testing example dataset (BB) - Testing Example Dataset (AA)
            & 12.34567\%    & 12.34567\%    & 12.34567\%    & 1.234 & 12.34567\%    & 12.34567\%    \cr
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]
\item[a]    SE: Standard Error
\item[b]    STT: Signal (Two Tailed)
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. I tried mine code, I adding `\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Bootstrap}} \\
\cmidrule{4-8}`. but the word not centre. I can post a new questions

Comment: @aan, please compare your test with mine answer. I put three ampersands before `\multicolumn{5}{c} (...}`. From your provided image follows, that "Bootstrap" is above last five columns.